# postgres - enumerate and null/blank cell

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a table `fruits` I have a column that is of Enumerated type, like so:

```
create type enum_fruits_fruit_color as enum ('red', 'yellow', 'orange');
```

The column `fruit_color` can only accept one of those 3 values. What if in the cell, I just want to insert a blank/empty value? Do I *have* to use **null**?

Is using **null** in this scenario the accepted practice, or is it also okay to just insert an empty value, and have that as one of the Enumerated options like so:

```
create type enum_fruits_fruit_color as enum ('', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange');
```

Comment: I would highly recommend you NOT have a '' as one of your enum values. Just use NULL where required e.g. `SELECT your_function(NULL)` and then handle NULL in your function, or create a value like 'none' if you really need to have an actual enum value.

Comment: Great, that's all I wanted to know. Thanks.